# What phonetic word form can generate the largest number of valid English words when adding single vowel sounds?

Tags: wordplay, english, language

If you take the phonetic word form /fl* (where * denotes any vowel sound), you can create (at least) 6 valid English words:

flay, flee, fly, flow, flue, flaw.

Which single-vowel phonetic word form can make the most valid English words by interchanging vowel sounds?

Comment: By the way, words like these are called minimal pairs. Would you consider sounds like *ar,* *or,* *er* to be vowels or sequences of a vowel and a consonant?

Comment: If you're British, try *bad, bed, bid, bod, bud, baaed, baud, booed, bowed, bowed, bead, bayed, bide, buoyed, bared, beard, bird*. That's 17. Note that *bowed* and *bowed* are pronounced differently. And also note *board*, *bard* (which are homophones for *baud* and *baaed* in BrE.)

Comment: Adding to @PeterShor 's list: I think that Ladefoged uses the hVd series in his phonetics textbook. *heed, hid, hayed, head, had, hawed, who'd, hood, HUD, hoed*. I think this gets you all of the monophthongs in AE other than open-o.

Comment: @jlovegren: if you don't have the *cot/caught* merger, you have to add *hod*. (A word I know from *The Bricklayer's Song,* aka *The Sick Note*.)

Comment: @jlovegren: For more-complex sounds, you also get _hide_, _hewed_, and _how'd_; and in Brooklyn, _hoyd_ (_heard_). But _HUD_ is as often as not pronounced as an initialism (H-U-D), so you might do better there with [Paul Newman is] _Hud_.

Comment: @Drew and the other close-voters: it is called English **phonetics**. This is a branch of English linguistics. Researchers actually look for lists of words like this when studying English dialectal variation... Coloring a map with four colors is a puzzle, but I somehow doubt that discussion of the topic would be closed off on Math.SE.

Comment: Is there a dataset containing the english dictionary represented phonetically? It seems like such a dataset could be used to solve this and a formal approach to answering it would demonstrate the value of the question.

Comment: This depends on various details of your accent, including what mergers it has and whether it is rhotic or not. I agree with the suggestion to use Ladefoged's series /hVd/; if I recall correctly, it covers every vowel phoneme usually used to transcribe English, although some of the words are obscure, like *hod*.

Comment: @Michael - Are you intending for this to be only for different phonemes (where aye and eye are the same), or for any lexicographically different words (where ah and aah are different)?

Answer (score 4):

The question doesn't make this clear and I'm not good with phonetics, so I'll make these assumptions:

1. you're looking for 1 syllable words only
2. each word must end in a 'vowel sound', which excludes hard consonant endings like 'ed'

With the above, I wrote a list of vowel-sound endings (I might have missed some):

```
suffixes = ['aa', 'ough', 'ae', 'ai', 'ah', 'ir', 'ea', 'ar', 'au', 'o', 'aw', 'ay', 'ei', 'ew', 'ie', 'er', 'ear', 'ier', 'owe', 'ire', 'igh', 'oo', 'augh', 'y', 'aigh', 'ee', 'ye', 'ooh', 'ow', 'oor', 'ore', 'a', 'e', 'err', 'i', 'oe', 'oa', 'ur', 'eigh', 'u', 'urr', 'ue', 'ey', 'ou', 'or']
```

And ran a python script which joins all possible prefixes ('thr','sp','tr','fl' etc) to all possible vowel-sound endings and checks if the result is a word. The winners are:

18 words:

```
['pea', 'par', 'po', 'paw', 'pay', 'pew', 'pie', 'per', 'pear', 'pier', 'pee', 'pooh', 'pow', 'poor', 'pore', 'pa', 'pi', 'purr']
```

19 words:

```
['tough', 'tai', 'tea', 'tar', 'tau', 'to', 'taw', 'tie', 'tear', 'tier', 'tire', 'too', 'tee', 'tow', 'tore', 'terr', 'ti', 'toe', 'tor']
 ['baa', 'bough', 'bah', 'bar', 'bay', 'bear', 'bier', 'boo', 'by', 'bee', 'bye', 'bow', 'boor', 'bore', 'be', 'boa', 'bur', 'burr', 'bey']
```

23 words:

```
['hah', 'ho', 'haw', 'hay', 'hew', 'hie', 'her', 'hear', 'howe', 'hire', 'high', 'haugh', 'hee', 'how', 'ha', 'he', 'herr', 'hi', 'hoe', 'heigh', 'hue', 'hey', 'hor']
```

This was using [this](http://www-01.sil.org/linguistics/wordlists/english/wordlist/wordsEn.txt) dictionary, with others your mileage may vary.

Comment: The question doesn't appear to restrict the phonetic to being a prefix, just that there must be exactly one other sound added and it must be a vowel sound. Making `asp` an addition to your `sp` list, for example.

Comment: That doesn't change the outcome (I checked with another python script). Which makes sense because the longer the prefix the less words there will be which match it (therefore single character prefixes come out on top).

Comment: @Ian MacDonald The question does imply it - the asterisk is where the vowel sound should be added.

Comment: @astralfenix If you're including -r endings, you might want to include -eer and -oar. Other endings I can think of are -eu and -ieu (as in milieu). Additionally, just because the combination can often be a vowel sound, does not mean it is within the word used (see, e.g., tough).

Comment: @charfellow: If the asterisk in the question is meant as anything more than an example, then the question *also* stipulates that you must use the prefix "fl". Because I'm pretty sure that's not the case, there is no reason to believe that the asterisk anything more than part of the example.

Comment: @IanMacDonald My interpretation of the authors writing is that, for example, tea (/t*) and eat (/*t) are different phonetic word forms as intended by the author. I am considering the asterisk to be a sort of wildcard symbol in the question (thus /fl* as the example phonetic word form).

Comment: @charfellow you're right about the -r endings and the 'tough' point. The latter did occur to me but for some reason I didn't bother to manually remove those from the results (no way I can see to script it).